# How Can I Loop Through All Objects Inside A Compound CCArray

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I'm working on a project which required me to create an CCArray that contains more CCArrays. I'm looking for a way to loop through all objects within the arrays housed inside the root array. I'd like to loop through all 15 objects using CCARRAY_FOREACH. Is this possible?

- rootArray [0] - Contains subArrayA full of 5 objects
- rootArray [1] - Contains subArrayB full of 5 objects
- rootArray [2] - Contains subArrayC full of 5 objects

I've used CCARRAY_FOREACH when using a CCSpriteBatchNode by using CCARRAY_FOREACH([batchnode children], object) but how can I use with an array of arrays? I know CCARRAY_FOREACH(rootArray, object) won't work since it returns the inside arrays and not the objects inside those arrays.

Let me know and sorry if a noob question. :0/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
CCARRAY_FOREACH(array, innerArray) 
{
    CCARRAY_FOREACH(innerArray, item) 
    {
        // stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use foreach loop...

```
for(CCArray *array in yourArray)
{
 for(YourObject *obj in array)
  {
       //access objects here
  }
}
```

Check for the syntax as I don't have x-code right now.. Its just a snippet.. Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: There is no foreach keyword. Just use 'for'.

Comment: Thank you! I'm not sure how I never even thought of a nested CCARRAY_FOREACH! I tested it and it works great! Here is what I used as code for anyone looking for exact code:

CCARRAY_FOREACH(arrayOfArrayOfObjects, arrayOfObjects)
{
 CCARRAY_FOREACH(arrayOfObjects, object)
 {
   // Do stuff here...
 }
}

Answer (score 0):

Recursion is your friend.

```
-(void) recurseIntoArray:(CCArray*)array
{
    for (id item in array)
    {
        if ([item isKindOfClass:[CCArray class]])
        {
             [self recurseIntoArray:(CCArray*)item];
        }
        else
        {
             NSLog(@"item: %@", item);
        }
    }
}
```

Just start the iteration anywhere with the root array:

```
[self recurseIntoArray:rootArray];
```

Worth mentioning: CCARRAY_FOREACH is no longer necessary, at least in cocos2d 1.1 and 2.0 you can just use regular fast iteration with for. May also work in cocos2d 1.0.1, I think I used fast enumeration there as well.

Comment: Wow...never thought of doing it this way either. Thanks and all of us noobs out here are grateful for your site!!! :0)

Comment: Recursion is more expensive than iteration.